# How to setup different names for variables in Android Firebase database?

Tags: android, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

I have class called "someThing". I need to save this class to Firebase not as "something", but as "some_thing". I can save it with HashMap, but it is not clear to me, how to get values back (mainly for adapter).

```
public class Something {

  private int someThing;

  public Something(int someThing) {
    this.someThing = someThing;
  }

  public int getSomeThing() {
    return someThing;
  }

  public void setSomeThing(int someThing) {
    this.someThing = someThing;
  }

}
```

Converting data to hash map for saving:

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("some_thing", something_value);
    return result;
}
```

But how to load them back into adapter? Adapter is basic adapter:

```
public class SomethingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Something> {
   public SomethingAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank to [Ahmed Abidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768929/ahmed-abidi), here is solution:

```
public class Something {

@PropertyName("some_thing")
private int someThing;

 public Something(int someThing) {
 this.someThing = someThing;
 }

 @PropertyName("some_thing")
 public int getSomeThing() {
 return someThing;
 }

 @PropertyName("some_thing")
 public void setSomeThing(int someThing) {
 this.someThing = someThing;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Firebase Annotations [`@PropertyName`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName)